# Add custom value to google map directons

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, post

How can i read custom field value and set as start & end in order to display google direction

```
function calcRoute() {
var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
var waypts = [];
var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
  waypts.push({
      location:checkboxArray[i].value,
      stopover:true});
}
}
```

In wordpress post i have 2 custom fields with start and destination value and i wish to read values and add to function calcroute() in order to display that route on google maps.

my entire code (below) display only centred view of Chicago

```
<script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 6,
center: chicago
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
var start = document.getElementById('plecare_din').value;
var end = document.getElementById('destinatie').value;
var waypts = [];
var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
 if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
  waypts.push({
      location:checkboxArray[i].value,
      stopover:true});
 }
}

var request = {
   origin: start,
  destination: end,
  waypoints: waypts,
  optimizeWaypoints: true,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to trigger the `calcRoute()` somewhere

I have a working sample here in jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/th9kwzdr/1/